# Transferring files from host to guest in Virtual Box broken

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a Windows host and an Ubuntu guest. I have drag-and-drop and copy-and-paste enabled both ways. When I try to drag or copy a folder over I get the folder but none of the contents. Tried with other folders to different locations. Same result. Kind of a noob when it comes to Linux and VirtualBox but after a while of looking I couldn't find anything. Guest Additions is installed.

Answer (score 0):

This may help. https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=4386

Also do you have quest additions installed.

Comment: Not trying to share, just copy/drag over.

Comment: It may be best to ask at the official forums, they have more info on it.